# How to create dynamic views

Tags: python, django-views

I was wondering if anyone could provide some insight into dynamic views in Django / Python? I thought it would be useful to have a drop down menu and then depending on the chosen result, determines the subsequent data being displayed to the end user.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseBadRequest, request
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.urls import path
from Healthcare.Conditions.Blood.blood import AcuteMyeloidLeukemia as a, ChronicMyeloidLeukemia as b, AcuteLymphoblasticLeukemia as c, NonHodgkinLeukemia as d, HodgkinLymphoma as e, Myeloma as f, MyelodysplasticSyndrome as g, AplasticAnaemia as h, Autoimmunediseases as i, Sicklecelldisease as j, Thalassaemia as k

def symptoms_view(self):
    if dropdown == 'AcuteMyeloidLeukemia':    
        sample_set = a()
        x = sample_set.my_symptoms().values()
        return HttpResponse(x)
    elif dropdown == 'ChronicMyeloidLeukemia':
        sample_set = b()
        x = sample_set.my_symptoms().values()
        return HttpResponse(x)
    elif dropdown == 'AcuteLymphoblasticLeukemia':
        sample_set = c()
        x = sample_set.my_symptoms().values()
        return HttpResponse(x)
    elif dropdown == 'NonHodkinLeukemia':
        sample_set = d()
        x = sample_set.my_symptoms().values()
        return HttpResponse(x)
    elif dropdown == 'HodgkinLeukemia':
        sample_set = e()
        x = sample_set.my_symptoms().values()
        return HttpResponse(x)
    elif dropdown == 'Myeloma':
        sample_set = f()
        x = sample_set.my_symptoms().values()
        return HttpResponse(x)
    elif dropdown == 'MyelodysplasticSyndrome':
        sample_set = g()
        x = sample_set.my_symptoms().values()
        return HttpResponse(x)
    elif dropdown == 'AplasticAneamia':
        sample_set = h()
        x = sample_set.my_symptoms().values()
        return HttpResponse(x)
    elif dropdown == 'Autoimmunediseases':
        sample_set = i()
        x = sample_set.my_symptoms().values()
        return HttpResponse(x)
    elif dropdown == 'Sicklecelldiseases':
        sample_set = j()
        x = sample_set.my_symptoms().values()
        return HttpResponse(x)
    elif dropdown == 'Thalassaemia':
        sample_set = k()
        x = sample_set.my_symptoms().values()
        return HttpResponse(x)
```

Comment: How to create a drop down or series of if statements to change the output of a view depending upon user choice.

Comment: Just following up from this I wondered whether it was possible to use an input to control the output of a view?